# Xcode 7.3.1 : Set background image to UINavigationBar and display back button

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I want to set logo of app as background image to `UINavigationBar` and when user traverse into app it should display **logo as well as back button on top of it.**

Below is code that I've used :

```
 func setNavigationBar() {
        let navigationBarHeight: CGFloat = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.height
        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

        let objCustomView = CustomView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenSize.width, height: navigationBarHeight))

        let objWindow = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
        objWindow?.addSubview(objCustomView)

        self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(false, animated:true);
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title:"", style:.Plain, target:nil, action:nil)                
    }
```

The issue with this is that **back button goes behind the image.**

[image: Screenshot 1]

**How to fix this?**

After refering post by **@NDoc** I'm getting extra space in left. Why so?
*Also, the back button should be white with no back text i.e. only < arrow.*

Below is code for customView :

```
class CustomView: UIView {      
    var imgLogo = UIImageView(frame:CGRectZero)

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds        
        imgLogo.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenSize.width, 44.0)

        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        setup()
    }

    func setup() {
        imgLogo.image = UIImage(named:"BoM_Logo")
        self.addSubview(imgLogo)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can display your logo in `leftBarButtonItem` and set the `leftItemsSupplementBackButton` to `true` to display `backButton` also like this.

```
let logoView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 30))
logoView.image = UIImage(named: "Logo")
let item = UIBarButtonItem(customView: logoView)
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = item
```

To show the back button with your logo image set `leftItemsSupplementBackButton` to `true`

```
self.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
```

**Edit:**

If you want custom arrow then you need to use `leftBarButtonItems` and pass array of `BarButtonItem` and no need to set `leftItemsSupplementBackButton` to `true` like this.

```
let logoView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 30))
logoView.image = UIImage(named: "Logo")
let logoItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: logoView)
let btnBack = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 25, height: 25))
btnBack.setImage(UIImage(named: "Back_Arrow"), forState: .Normal)
btnBack.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonAction(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
let backItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btnBack)     
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [backItem, logoItem]
```

**Note:** Don't forgot to add `buttonAction` action method inside your viewController.

Comment: Pls check question. I've another issue by using this code

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your appDelegate

```
let image = UIImage.init(named:"upper-bar.png")
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(image,forBarMetrics:UIBarMetrics.Default)
```

for back button try this in the viewDidLoad() of your viewController

```
let image1 = UIImage(named: "go10.png") as UIImage?
let btnLeft = UIButton(type: .Custom)
btnLeft.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 25)
btnLeft.setImage(image1,forState:UIControlState.Normal)
btnLeft.addTarget(self, action:(#selector(NameofyourViewController.backBtn(_:))),forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

let leftBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btnLeft)
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButton
@IBAction func backBtn(sender: UIButton)
{
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```